# Hide a specific Woocommerce products from loop if they are in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I'm trying to write a hook that hides a specific product from the shop page if it's in the cart, but I can't seem to figure out two things.

```
function find_product_in_cart() {

    $hide_if_in_cart = array(6121, 6107, 14202, 14203);
    $in_cart = false;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];

        foreach ( $hide_if_in_cart as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $product_in_cart === $value ) {
                $in_cart = true;
            }
        }

        if ( $in_cart ) {
            echo 'Product in cart';
        } else {
            echo 'Not in cart!';
        }

    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'find_product_in_cart
```

1. The code prints out "Product in cart" everywhere, because one product with ID '14202' is in the cart. My logic is wrong somewhere...
2. I don't know how to hide a single product, right now I print a line of text, but I want to be able to either display: none; it or maybe use a specific function that hides product in certain scenario's.

This is the output at the moment:
https://i.gyazo.com/d85bd93598ada7aa96bee9a1d7393c3c.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will remove a specific defined products from Woocommerce shop and archive pages when they are in cart, using this dedicated Woocommerce action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_specific_products_from_shop', 20, 2 );
function hide_specific_products_from_shop( $q, $query ) {
    if( is_admin() && WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return;

    // HERE Set the product IDs in the array
    $targeted_ids = array( 6121, 6107, 14202, 14203 );

    $products_in_cart = array();

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_ids ) ){
            // When any defined product is found we add it to an array
            $products_in_cart[] = $cart_item['product_id'];
        }
    }
    // We remove the matched products from woocommerce lopp
    if( count( $products_in_cart ) > 0){
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $products_in_cart );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks, this piece of code did the trick. I learned two things.

First, I forgot to that I had to add every product in cart to an array.

I learned about set() and post__not_in.

Thanks

Comment: Hello Loic, I have a little question regarding your answer. At the end you set the query to not display any products that are in the products_in_cart array. You do this via $q->set(....). Now I know $q is the Query variable for woocommerce.

But how do you know what to use in the set(). Like here you used 'post__not_in'. I have been google'ing a bit but I can't find much information about this.

Is there some documentation regadring this subject somewhere that you know of? Or how do you find out about these things?

Comment: @ArneDeBelser This is not really related to Woocommerce but to Wordpress [`WP_Query` Class in Post and page parameters section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)… The [`WC_Query` Woocommerce Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Query.html) extend in some way the `WP_Query` Class. Don't forget that "product" is a Wordpress custom post and Woocommerce a Wordpress plugin. So the underground foundation is still WordPress.

Comment: I was thiking the wrong way. Thanks for clarifying that, I understand!