# Remove Add do Cart Button for customers and guests for specifics products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, code-snippets

For Woocommerce, I need a PHP snippet that will hide few products ID's **I will select** for **guests** and **customers**.

My code attempt:

```php
function dma_restrict_product() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user->ID);
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;
    
    global $product;

    if( in_array( 'customer', (array) $user_roles ) && ( is_single('3759') ) ) {
        return true;
        add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_cloudways_purchasable');
        
        function woocommerce_cloudways_purchasable($cloudways_purchasable, $product) {
            return ($product->id == 3759 ? false : $cloudways_purchasable);
        }

    } else if( in_array('administrator', (array) $user_roles) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work as I would like.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to hide the product completly:**

You can hide products by using the ID of the product and exclude it from the product query:

```
function hide_my_product( $q ) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user->ID);
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

    if ( !in_array( 'administrator', $user_roles ) ) {

        // id of product to hide
        $product_id = 3759; 
        // exclude the id from query
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $product_id );
    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_my_product' );
```

---

**If you want to hide the add to cart button of product:**

If you want to list the product with price, but only hide the "Add to Cart" button, you can do this with the `woocommerce_is_purchasable` hook, that will return false for your product ids and therefore will show the price, but in the place of "Add to Cart" button the notice "Product cannot be purchased" appears.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'hide_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );

function hide_add_to_cart_button( $purchasable = true, $product ) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user->ID);
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

    if ( !in_array( 'administrator', $user_roles ) && $product->get_id() == 3759 ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }
  
    return $purchasable;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 different request on your question *(one in the title and another a bit different in the body)*:

1). To avoid guests and customers to purchase some defined products *(hiding or disabling add to cart button)*, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'restrict_purchases_on_defined_product', 10, 2 );
function restrict_purchases_on_defined_product( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    // For guest users or  "customer" user role
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can( 'customer' ) ) {

        // HERE define your product ID(s) that will noot be purchassable
        $restricted_product_ids = array(37, 53, 70);

        if ( array_intersect( array( $product->get_id(), $product->get_parent_id() ), $restricted_product_ids ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

2). To hide completely some defined products from guests and customers, use the following:

```
// Settings: HERE define your product ID(s) that will not be purchasable
function my_hidden_product_ids() {
    return array(37, 53, 70);
}

// Hide some products from product loops
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_defined_product' );
function hide_defined_product( $query ) {
    // For guest users or  "customer" user role
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can( 'customer' ) ) {
        $hidden_product_ids = my_hidden_product_ids();

        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $hidden_product_ids );
    }
}

// Redirect some product pages to main shop page (for security)
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_defined_product_single_pages' );
function redirect_defined_product_single_pages( $query ) {
    // For guest users or  "customer" user role
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can( 'customer' ) ) {
        $hidden_product_ids = my_hidden_product_ids();

        if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $hidden_product_ids ) ) {
            wp_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
}

// Check and remove related cart items silently (for security)
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'remove_specific_products_from_cart', 10, 1 );
function remove_specific_products_from_cart( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // For guest users or  "customer" user role
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can( 'customer' ) ) {
        $hidden_product_ids = my_hidden_product_ids();

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach (  $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            if ( array_intersect( array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] ), $hidden_product_ids ) ) {
                $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Hide a specific Woocommerce products from loop if they are in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592964/hide-a-specific-woocommerce-products-from-loop-if-they-are-in-cart/49593292#49593292)